# mysqldump add TABLESPACE definition that fails during import

Tags: mysql

While importing from sqldump, the following error is encountered.

ERROR 1812 (HY000) at line 753: InnoDB: A general tablespace named `TABLESPACE_NAME` cannot be found.

Used the following following command to import and export.

Export: `mysqldump -h $DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD --complete-insert --routines --triggers --single-transaction "$dbname" > "$dbname".sql`

Import: `mysql -h $server -u $user -p$password $dbname < $sql;`

The same scripts created dump with no (TABLESPACE definitions) when dump against one of the other database servers while the one in AWS (RDS 5.7) resulted in dump with TABLESPACE definition. 
Currently, dump should be exported from mysql 5.7 to mysql 5.7 running as docker container.

Should the definition be excluded while dumping or the definition be excluded while importing? Either ways, I need help from DB experts about command options to import such a database.

Comment: check the permissions of the .ibd file matching your table.  maybe running your mysql command with sudo will overcome the permissions issue.  in short, if that's not it, it could [also be a problem](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-tablespace-is-missing-for-table/) with the table file having been corrupted or deleted.

Comment: There was no issue with the file @WEBjuju.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and tests, this is what my understanding is.

When databases are created with tablespaces, mysqldump does not include the tablespace definitions. There is no option with mysqldump to ignore tablespace references. So, I had two options after taking dump.
1. Edit the dump manually and remove the references to tablespace. 
2. Create the tablespace before importing the dump.

I had a luxury to import into a server that was running as container. So, mysql listed all the tablespaces that were not available (After such error reported, I could throw away the mysql container and start another one - to feel that the server is fresh). Since I knew all the tablespaces, I went with the second option and also thought that editing the dump created by tool (mysqldump) is not a good idea.

Used the following statement to create tablespace

```
create tablespace <tablespace-name> add datafile 'tablespace-name.ibd'
```

This approach worked for me.

Comment: Removing the reference to table space worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wasn't able to create the tablespace on the db because it was shared hosting and required server admin privileges to do so, but I was able to use the generated error code to find the textual reference to the tablespace in the dump file. It is consistent every time, so a simple find and delete search took care of the whole file, and then the transaction completed with no errors.